# What non-essential directories can I exclude from TimeMachine?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I want to have the most # of backups of my actual files, not of temporary files, and easily restorable data.

- What can I exclude from a Time Machine backup to get the most efficient backups?

(I use VMs, so tips for Parallels, Virtual Box, etc, are welcome)

In the sample below, I blocked

- Backups of all Drive sync technology (Google Drive, One Drive, etc)
- Xamarin project output (in the Simulator).  All this is stale cached data
- iOS emulators with Xcode.
- Stuff in the MacOS app store
- Stuff in the iTunes App Store
- Backups of my iPhone devices

[image]

Comment: You can't back up part of a VM unfortunately, the entire drive is flagged as changed, so you'll gain the most space by excluding them. Use snapshots & allow those to backup.

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient backups would mean leaving Time Machine alone, not twisting knobs randomly.

The only thing you should be excluding are the VM's.